# List setter is not being called when appending a new value

Tags: kotlin

I had a workaround solution for this problem which involves reassigning the variable to itself; however, this doesn't seem efficient.

```
fun main() {

    val x = Example1()
    x.listOfInt = mutableListOf(3,4)
    x.listOfInt.add(455)
}

class Example1 {

  var listOfInt: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
    set(value) { 
        println("setting it here to value => $value")
         field = value 
    }
}
// It only prints:
// setting it here to value => [3, 4]
```

As you can see, the setter doesn't get triggered when the value is appended which effectively changing the value of the collection. Is there a better way to do this?

Here's a link to the code on Kotlin's [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/u8t84g0Fp)

The reason this is odd to me because of the below similar code in Swift which does the expected when the Array is appended:

```swift
import Foundation

class Example1 {
  var fieldProperty: Int = 0

  var listOfInt: [Int] = [] {
    didSet { 
        print("setting it here to value => \(listOfInt) vs oldValue: \(oldValue)")      
    }
  }
}

let x = Example1()
x.listOfInt = [3,4]
x.listOfInt.append(455)

// this prints:
// setting it here to value => [3, 4] vs oldValue: []
// setting it here to value => [3, 4, 455] vs oldValue: [3, 4]
```

I know I might be comparing apples to oranges, but I'm just curious if there's a better solution.

Comment: *when the value is appended which effectively changing the value of the collection* but it does not change the value of `listOfInt`. The value of the list **does not change** when you append items to it. It is the same list with new items.

Comment: The `set` is only called when you reassign the variable `listOfInt` inside the `Example1` object, not when you call a method on that variable such as `add()`.

Comment: If you don't want anyone to change the content of the list referenced by `x` without using the setter, then don't use a mutable list. Use an immutable one.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `set(value) { }` is the equivalent of implementing a setter on that variable.
The code you provided could be interpreted as:

```
class Example1 {

    var listOfInt: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()

    fun set(value: MutableList<Int>) { 
        println("setting it here to value => $value")
        this.listOfInt = value 
    }
}
```

When you call `x.listOfInt.add(455)` you are calling the `add` method on the list defined in the `x` instance of `Example1`.

Try calling `x.listOfInt = mutableListOf(1,2,3)` and you'll see your setter will correctly get called.

To implement what you want to do, there is several ways:

1. Implement a new version of `MutableList<>` which overrides the method `add` (this *might* be overkill).
2. Create a `add` method in your `Example1` class which will look like this:

   ```
   fun add(value: Int) {
       println("adding value to list => $value")
       listOfInt.add(value)
   }
   ```

You main will now look like this:

```
fun main() {
    val x = Example1()
    x.listOfInt = mutableListOf(3,4)
    x.add(455)
}
```